# hibernate validator for non blank fields

Tags: java, jsp, validation, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

How we can validate our fields using hibernate validator only when our inputs are not blank ?

suppose we want to leave an input text as an arbitrary field but we want to validate it if it is not blank using hibernate validator. how we can do this ?

Comment: Just adding the not null clause wont help? nullable=false

Comment: not null just make sure the field is not null. please read the question carefully

Comment: Can you show some code? What have you tried? To be honest, I am not sure what you are actually asking?